# An UI element is not showing on iPad air 2 after installing the .ipa file of project for testing but works on other iPads(iPad mini, iPad 2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ad-hoc-distribution, uielement

When I run and debug my app everything is working fine, but when I create an `.ipa` file using save for ad-hoc deployment option and install it using iTunes or for testing on iPad air 2, some of the UI elements are not shown on iPad Air 2.

However it **does** work for other iPads like iPad mini and iPad 2. I have not tested other devices yet.

Unfortunately, my app is only for iPad so I have to fix this issue.

Comment: Could this be related to resolution? @2x ? (iPad 2 and iPad mini are not Retina)

Comment: i dnt know the reason. @Larme can you tell me the solution if it happening due to resolution?

Comment: What's not showing ? images ?

Comment: Larme could be on the right track alright as the simulators doesn't handle .@3x. Do you include some .@3x images in your app and none for this piece of UI? Even still it should revert to the .@2x. Have you looked at using revealapp?

Answer (score 0):

Finally After trying a lot I found the solution but did not get the reason till now.
In my code I used

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showHideCountTimerView:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] afterDelay:0.4f];
```

but when I used -

```
 [self showHideCountTimerView:NO];
```

and Its working.
Now the view which is not shown is showing on iPad air 2 on install the .ipa file